# Conveyor Truss Analysis Problem with loading

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structures

I've been working on a schematic and its been going beyond my comprehension; so i thought i should consult better structural engineers here. (I'm a fresh Civil Engr Graduate though)

i have this scheme shown below, where the task is to design a truss carrying a conveyor mechanism. i'm able to calculate trusses of any type with correct loading parameters, but this scheme has been eluding me for hours.

[image: Elevation of scheme]

so i simplified it to this for proper analysis
[image: Elevation of scheme(Simplified)]

The issue is that, i know trusses cannot carry load on their members as done in the scheme where 7.3 KN is applied. This is where the problem is, am i missing something? this is my first conveyor truss analysis, i really hope this QA site will shed a lot more light on this matter. Thanks

Comment: Is the truss the structure composed of those super slender elements, including the diagonals, most of which has been cropped out of your picture? If so, please [edit] your post to include the full structure.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that, i know trusses cannot carry load on their members

Not quite right. ***Idealised*** trusses can't carry load applied within the length of the member, and can only carry load applied at nodes.

In reality an individual truss member can act as a beam. You need to design it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Several things you may want to know:

1. Ussualy, those schematics are only orientative. Maybe you can move members. If you really need it you can put a profile under the load. You have to draw a quick schema and send it to the PM for aproval.
2. A truss can only carry loads on nodes but, you can design a chord as a continuous beam. This chord may carry loads wherever you want. The truss will be designed as a typical truss but your chord will need complementary design. You will need to check both axial and lateral loads (of course combined).
3. Be careful designing that chord. Remember to take into account the bendings when designing buckling and lateral buckling. Your analysis program will do it wrong.